# ECB and CBC AES output is equal in Java

Tags: java, encryption, aes, cbc-mode, ecb

I've played around with the Java AES En/Decryption and used different cyper modes for this. Namely I use CBC and ECB. As ECB is considered to be weak, I wanted to go with CBC.

I assumed the output of the encrypted texts ob cbc and ecb are different, but they are equal. How is this possible?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

import com.instana.backend.common.exception.InstanaException;

public class AESTest {

  private static String pwd = "etjrgp9user9fu3984h1&(/&%$§";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("UNSECURE WITH ECB:");
    String ecbEncrypt = encrypt("YOLO", cypher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, "AES"));
    System.out.println("Encrypted: " + ecbEncrypt);

    String ebcDecrypt = decrypt(ecbEncrypt, cypher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, "AES"));
    System.out.println("Decrypted: " + ebcDecrypt);

    System.out.println("=====================================");
    System.out.println("SECURE WITH CBC");

    String cbcEncrypt = encrypt("YOLO", cypher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"));
    System.out.println("Encrypted: " + cbcEncrypt);

    String cbcDecrypt = decrypt(cbcEncrypt, cypher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"));
    System.out.println("Decrypted: " + cbcDecrypt);

    System.out.println("=====================================");
    System.out.println("Decrypting CBC with ECB");


  }

  public static String encrypt(String superDuperSecret, Cipher cipher) throws IOException {
    try {
      byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(superDuperSecret.getBytes("UTF-8"));

      return new String(new Hex().encode(encrypted));

    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new InstanaException("Encryption of token failed.", e);
    }
  }

  public static String decrypt(String superDuperSecret, Cipher cipher) {
    try {
      byte[] encrypted1 = new Hex().decode(superDuperSecret.getBytes("UTF-8"));

      return new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted1));

    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new InstanaException("Encrypted text could not be decrypted.", e);
    }
  }

  private static Cipher cypher(int mode, String method)
      throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidKeySpecException,
      InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(pwd.toCharArray(), pwd.getBytes(), 128, 128);
    SecretKey tmp = skf.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(method);

    if(method.contains("CBC")) {
      byte[] ivByte = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
      IvParameterSpec ivParamsSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivByte);

      cipher.init(mode, key, ivParamsSpec);
    }else{
      cipher.init(mode, key);
    }

    return cipher;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're passing an empty IV (you never put anything inside your `ivByte`), the operations performed for the first block are identical regardless of the mode being used. Encrypting a longer payload would result in the second block being chained to the first block in the case of `CBC` and the following blocks would be different between ECB/CBC.

You should pass a non-empty IV when using CBC mode, so the first block will be xorred with the IV, resulting in different encrypted values starting from the first block.

Comment: would you give me an example? Just a small simple one. Thanks

Comment: Encrypt a longer String. One that's longer than the blocksize.

Comment: That's not correct. The IV, when properly generated, is applied to the first block and then the chaining begins. The OP is only getting this result because he isn't generating an IV properly.

Comment: What do I need to change in the code to implement this correctly?

Comment: @Christian Use a random IV. Just prefix it to the encrypted data for use in decryption, it does not need to not secret.

Comment: @zaph But it *is* related to input length. His broken code results in identical first encrypted blocks, but the following blocks would differ.

Comment: No, see [Cipher Block Chaining (CBC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29) for information on CBC mode. Notice that if the IV is all 0x00 bytes it has no effect on the first block. If an IV is specified that is not all 0x00 byres the first block will be affected.

Comment: @zaph I know what CBC is. And due to the empty IV, the first block is identical, although the following ones (not seen due to the short payload) are different. That's what I'm saying in the first paragraph, but it may be a bit unclear. He **should** use an IV, but because he's not he gets the first block as identical with ECB and CBC.

Comment: @zaph I'll reword it, although the sentence is correct and explains what he saw.

Comment: if you use the ECB and use thr IVm then you will get this exception: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: ECB mode cannot use IV